# Delete Reports : One or more dashboards depend on this report

Tags: reporting, dashboard, migration, bulk-delete

First I have deleted dashboards using Force.com migration tool. I made sure there are no records in Recycle Bin. Later when I am trying to delete reports it's complaining

*One or more dashboards depend on this report. Please delete the dashboard components referring to this report and try again.*

I ran the Reports with Dashboards report. When I try to access the associated Dashboard component it says

*The record you attempted to access has been deleted. The user who deleted this record may be able to recover it from the Recycle Bin. Deleted data is stored in the Recycle Bin for 15 days.*

I am kind of stuck. Please help.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because too old to migrate.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to check out the Recycle Bin - You have "My Recycle Bin" and "All Recycle Bin". You will not find the deleted record under "My Recycle Bin" because it was deleted by another user. (see [here](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=home_delete.htm)

Perhaps you could try checking whether you can find it under "All", deleting it there and trying again.